# XML Rest Service consumption using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, xml, post

Is it viable to consume XML Response from a Webservice by posting xml using angular JS. Any suggestions would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be just convert the xml object to the json object
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-xml2json-plugin/

Comment: The service i am using only accepts XML as input and respond with XML as response